# Multiline textfield in C# changes layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout, textfield, multiline

I am using the ASP.net framework. I am building a web form using the design view of the .aspx file. I have made a very simple form, the below is the code in the .aspx file.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Height="60px" Width="550px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="60px" Text="Button"  Width="100px"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="60px" Text="Button" Width="100px" />
```

The problem is that when I set the TextMode to MultiLine the position of buttons changes too.
Textmode set to single line:
[image: single line]

Textmode set to multi line:
[image: multi line]

Any explanation for this?

Comment: This likely has to do with your CSS (or lack of) do you have a CSS reset in there?  What browser are you experiencing this on?

Comment: I am experiencing this on all the browser that I have used(Chrome,IE, Mozilla Firefox).

Comment: The problem was that the Multiline atributte changes the input box to a textarea, which requires some new css(vertical-align: top;).

Comment: Need to see the CSS to be able to be of any help.